# Centering page when zoomed in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, zooming, center

I am building a website for a client who wants their page to zoom perfectly in IE7. I have finally managed to get around most of the bugs, but one.

When you zoom in on the page, it centers fine, but then when you go to another page, the page renders and displays the top left of the page. I need to make it render centered. I know it is possible (the client keeps comparing it to bbc.co.uk which has this feature).

Does anyone know of a fix I can add to my body tag or something?! Let me know if you need to see any code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your site in a container div;

```
<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
```

and the css;

```
#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: XXXpx;
}
```

applied to it has the desired effect.

(Where width represents the width of the layout).

Zooms centered, and when moving through pages in the zoomed state stays centered. Tested in ie7 on VMware XP.

Answer (score 0):

When scale/zoom, the center point of IE seems at the top-left
I move to the center by scripts

```
$.browser.mozilla
    ? $container.css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')')
    : $container.css('zoom', scale)

winW = $(window).width()
winH = $(window).height()

if ($.browser.msie) {
    var offScale = (1 - scale) / 2
    $container.css({
        top   : winH * offScale
      , left  : winW * offScale
})
```

You must know the scale number and my position of $container is "absolute"